# On solving Double-Powers

Tags: contest-math

I was solving this question, and I'm hitting a wall.

> $x^{x^4}=4$, then what is ${x^{x^8}}+{x^{x^2}}$?

Taking $\log$,  $x^4\log\{x\}=\log\{4\}$,  so $1<x<2$. However, I don't think that taking a $Log$ again will help me, and since there is addition in the second equation, it shouldn't work there, too. Trial and error won't help, so I have no direction in which to continue. Can anyone help?

Comment: If this is a contest problem, are there answer choices?

Comment: @Nilknarf Subjective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raising the given equation to the fourth power, we get $$(x^4)^{x^4}=4^4,$$ and that means $x^4=4,$ since $f(x)=x^x$ is monotone increasing for $x\ge e^{-1}.$ So $x^{x^8}+x^{x^2}=\sqrt{2}^8+\sqrt{2}^2=258.$
The same method works with the equation $x^{x^\alpha}=\alpha,$ but it works well only for $\alpha>1$. For $\alpha<1,$ there may be (and for $\alpha\neq e^{-1},$ there will be) a second solution, which won't be easily expressed in terms of $\alpha.$

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
x^{\,x^{\,4} }  = 4\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {x^{\,x^{\,4} } } \right)^{\,2}  = x^{\,2\,x^{\,2} x^{\,2} }  = \left( {\left( {\,x^{\,2} } \right)^{\,x^{\,2} } } \right)^{\,x^{\,2} }  = 16
$$

then $x^2=2$ is a solution , and given that  the LHS is increasing (monotone) , that is the only real  positive solution.

The rest follows  easily.